# Getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following error when trying to subscribe to an endpoint. Here is my code and the response from the endpoint. When I console log the response, it shows data.

*TS*

```
this.getMemberDetails().subscribe((resp) => {
  console.log(resp.Member[0]);
  this.memberDetails = resp.Member[0];
}
```

*response data*

```
{
    "Member": [
        {
            "EmployeeId": "9f0b0c25-5c29-4cd1-beb8-722b09e7d8a2",
            "HrRepresentativeId": "522d6c01-90e4-4259-a848-d7c3716d58bc",
            "EmployeeNumber": "00187021",
            "EmployerName": "@ HOME",
            "ExitDate": "2020-07-28T00:00:00",
            "ExitNoticeDate": "2020-07-28T00:00:00",
            "IdentityValue": "6104060705088",
            "IdentityTypeId": 1,
            "EmployeeUserName": "",
            "Initials": "HH",
            "FirstName": "Hazel",
            "Surname": "Msibi",
            "DateOfBirth": "1961-04-06T00:00:00",
            "TelephoneNumber": "0112690000",
            "MobileNumber": "0844064716",
            "PersonalEmail": "c7f6304a6f@emailmonkey.club",
            "WorkEmail": "",
            "PrimaryEmail": "c7f6304a6f@emailmonkey.club",
            "IsHrEmailAddress": false,
            "IndebtedToEmployer": false,
            "AmountOfDeduction": 0.0,
            "POBox": null,
            "Address1": "122 test",
            "Address2": "abc",
            "Address3": "def",
            "UnitNumber": null,
            "Complex": null,
            "StreetNumber": null,
            "StreetOrFarmName": null,
            "SuburbOrDistrict": null,
            "CityOrTown": null,
            "Country": "SM",
            "PostalCode": "2196",
            "TitleId": 1,
            "GenderId": 1,
            "ModifiedBy": "cicoyos621@x7mail.com",
            "HrRepresentative": {
                "HrRepresentativeId": "522d6c01-90e4-4259-a848-d7c3716d58bc",
                "UserName": "cicoyos621@x7mail.com",
                "EmailAddress": "cicoyos621@x7mail.com",
                "ModifiedBy": "cicoyos621@x7mail.com",
                "FirstName": "xxxxx",
                "LastName": "xxxx"
            },
            "Membership": [
                {
                    "EmployeeMembershipId": 4744,
                    "EmployeeId": "9f0b0c25-5c29-4cd1-beb8-722b09e7d8a2",
                    "FundId": 2421,
                    "FundName": "Standard Bank Group Retirement Fund",
                    "IntegrationSystem": "Conventional",
                    "SubscriptionNumber": "M01532552",
                    "IsHybrid": false,
                    "ModifiedBy": "cicoyos621@x7mail.com",
                    "Gender": null,
                    "Title": null
                }
            ],
            "Exit": {
                "ExitId": "3e768898-ec65-4386-9a20-829f6d6ed079",
                "EmployeeId": "9f0b0c25-5c29-4cd1-beb8-722b09e7d8a2",
                "KickoffDate": "2020-05-13T00:00:00",
                "ActionId": 1,
                "StatusId": 1,
                "StatusDescription": "Started",
                "ActionDescription": "Resignation",
                "ModifiedBy": "6104060705088",
                "OpportunityId": null,
                "ClaimId": 0,
                "RBC": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Message": "Success"
}
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Are you looking for `Membership[0]` instead of `Member[0]` ?

Comment: @Emilien I am looking for `Member[0]`. I have updated the payload

Comment: Are you definitely getting the error at the point it runs the line this.memberDetails = resp.Member[0]; Or could it be that the error is happening later?

Comment: @Toby This is all I see in the browser console. I commented out everything else and still get this error

Comment: @skydev Maybe you can put a debugger statement just before the line this.memberDetails = resp.Member[0]; and confirm it definitely is erroring when you step over that line. Also would be good to post exactly what the data is that you see in the console.log. And if that doesn't reveal anything, the problem is likely in getMemberDetails(). Are you able to post what that is doing?